# How to give equal space between text objects in crystal report vs 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I want to know how to give equal space between text objects.Is there any
  option in crystal report visual studio 2012? I googled i found that there
  is an option. like

```
right click on report --> select Report--> then select
--> Style Expert. But i can't find style expert in my report design.After
right click on report -->point to Report --> no style expert option(?).
```

Can anyone tell me how to give equal space between multiple text object?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show image on what you want to view

Comment: Just i want to view "Style Expert" option. when i right click on crystal report design and point to "Report" In report it will show some options in that i can't find "Style Expert" option. If i find then we will get equal spaces between multiple text objects.